# Update query for MongoDB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How would you go about updating the 'status' attribute of the product "car" having a status of 0, to 1, in the purchases array of the following MongoDB Document.

MongoDB Document::

```
{
    "local": {
        "Name": "Rio",
        "Income": 300000,
        "purchases": [{
                "prod": "car",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "prod": "bike",
                "status": 0
            },
            {
                "prod": "car",
                "status": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator with [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update
>   without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the
>   array.

```
db.collection.update(
  { "local.purchases": { "$elemMatch": { "prod": "car", "status": 0 }}},
  { "$set": { "local.purchases.$.status": 1 }}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @anthony. Would explain me why we use that $ sign ?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Your answer is incorrect. It updates the status for bike not car. You've to use $elemMatch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) to match the array element on both criteria.

```
db.colname.update(
  {"local.purchases":{"$elemMatch":{"prod":"car", "status":0}}},
  {"$set":{"local.purchases.$.status":1}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will be :- db.sample.update({"local.purchases.status": 0}, {$set : {"local.purchases.$.status" : 1} });

Explanation:-
Here you will have to use $ operator to reference those purchases which are matched by the find query in the first argument fo the update function. Hope it helps.